# find maximum double in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, max, double

Here is the code, I keep not getting the correct output from the getMax method.
I fill an array with the sum of the int values of an ArrayList, then check which one of them is the smallest and the biggest, finally outputting them and pruning away the decimal places, which might cause errors maybe?
Code might be bad, I'm a noob:

```
public static void miniMaxSum(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
    
    double[] acc = new double[arr.size()]; 
    for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++){
        for (int j=0; j<arr.size(); j++){
            acc[i] += arr.get(j);
            }
        acc[i] -= arr.get(i);
        }
             
    //double min = acc[arr.size()-1];
    //double max = acc[0];
    System.out.printf("%.0f", getMin(acc));
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.printf("%.0f", getMax(acc));     
    }             

public static double getMin(double[] acc){
    double min = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<acc.length; j++){
        for (int i=0; i<acc.length; i++){
            if (acc[i] > acc[j]){
                min = acc[j];
            } else {
                min = acc[i];
            }
            
        }
    }     
    return min; 
}
public static double getMax(double[] acc){
    double max = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<acc.length; j++){
        for (int i=0; i<acc.length; i++){
            if (acc[i] > acc[j]){
                max = acc[i];
                System.out.println(max);
            } 
            else {
                max = acc[j];
            }
            
        }
    }     
    return max; 
}
```

Comment: why not sort the array and return the last element?

Comment: why do you need to have nested loops to find min-max? store the first element in your min/max variable, then compare each following element to that and replace if it is smaller/larger accordingly. After the last iteration you would have your min or max accordingly

Comment: @Stultuske  ok, that might be easier, but what exactly is wrong here?

Comment: @Stultuske sorting is not required to get the min or max value and will in general be slower than just looping throug the array once and finding min and max values. Nevertheless, everything OP wants do do can be done in one simple loop.

Comment: @Mushroomator i think what he means is that instead of filling array from arraylist then finding min/max, just sort the arraylist, out put index 0 and the index at arraylist.size() -1

Comment: Just musing about any possible difference in precision between `<` and `Double.compare` ...

Comment: ah right, the nested loops are useless as experiment unit says

Comment: @Mushroomator nothing is required, there 'll always be another way. but as for easy and understandable code, using a one-liner might very well make it harder to make mistakes in

Answer (score 1):

Method to do the checks yourself

```
public static double findMax(double[] data) {
    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (double val : data) {
        if (val > max) {
            max = val;
        }
    }
    
    return max;
}
```

Using the Math utility

```
public static double findMax2(double[] data) {
    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (double val : data) {
        max = Math.max(val, max);
    }
    
    return max;
}
```

Using streams

```
public static double findMax3(double[] data) {
    return Arrays.stream(data).max().getAsDouble();
}
```

Doing your own checks

```
public static double findMin(double[] data) {
    double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for (double val : data) {
        if (val < min) {
            min = val;
        }
    }
    
    return min;
}
```

Using Math utility

```
public static double findMin2(double[] data) {
    double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for (double val : data) {
        min = Math.min(val, min);
    }
    
    return min;
}
```

Using streams

```
public static double findMin3(double[] data) {
    return Arrays.stream(data).min().getAsDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything you want do do in a single loop. First calculate the sum for each value and then check for that sum if it is a new maximum and/ or minimum value. If any of these option is true, update the respective maximum or minimum value.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var test = new double[]{10d, 4.43d, 5.3d, -6.8d, 7.1d, 8.7d, 8.1d, 234d, -3.9d, -455.3d};
        minMaxSum(test);
    }

    public static void minMaxSum(double[] arr) {
        double acc = 0;
        // initialize the minimal value with the maximal value
        double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        // initialize the biggest value with the smallest possible value
        double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        var sum = new double[arr.length];
        // a single for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var cur = arr[i];
            // sum up adding the current value
            acc += cur;
            // save the current value in new array so we can verify the result (not actually required for the algorithm)
            sum[i] = acc;
            // if something is smaller than what we've already encountered => set new smallest value
            if(acc < min) min = acc;
            // if something is bigger than what we've already encountered => set new biggest value
            if(acc < max) max = acc;
        }
        System.out.printf("""
                Original:   %s
                Prefix-sum: %s
                Min: %s
                Max: %s
                """, Arrays.toString(arr), Arrays.toString(sum), min, max);
    }

}
```

Expected output:

```
Original:   [10.0, 4.43, 5.3, -6.8, 7.1, 8.7, 8.1, 234.0, -3.9, -455.3]
Prefix-sum: [10.0, 14.43, 19.73, 12.93, 20.03, 28.73, 36.83, 270.83, 266.93, -188.37]
Min: -188.37
Max: 270.83
```

As many people recommended sorting as a viable approach, here some remarks on sorting. First, yes, it would give you a correct result but there is a price to pay which is speed and well it is just an unnecessarily complex solution.

Sorting based on comparisons and without any pre-conditions [cannot be done faster than in `O(n log n)`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lower-bound-on-comparison-based-sorting-algorithms/). It is obvious that the solution above needs `O(n)` time thus is a complexity class faster. Also the constants (which are ignored in big-O notation) are quite small in the above solution, so even if some pre-conditions were met and you could use a special sorting algorithm like [Map sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxmap_sort) (or alike) which run in `O(n)` (again: under certain conditions) the above solution would still be faster and, not to mention, much simpler. So don't make your life harder than it needs to be.

Comment: oh i see, thanks this might be even easier

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to use nested loops for getMax or getMin functions.

```java
    public static double getMax(double[] acc){
        double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        for (double value : acc) {
            if( value > max) max = value;
        }
        return max;
    }
```

if you want to sort the list anyway:

```java
    public static void miniMaxSum(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
        if(arr.size() > 0) {
            Collections.sort(arr);
            System.out.println(arr.get(0));
            System.out.println(arr.get(arr.size() - 1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, sorting array in a general approach would not be faster.

Comment: You are right, thank you. You can search for min and max in a single loop, so O(n). (Edit my answer)